# As3 collision detection with a movieclip array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, movieclip

Ok my xChar.character is my character movieclip and xMap the instance of the class building the map.

From the xMap i add movieclip sliced from a image using variable which is inside a function. I do addChild(cell1); for every object displayed on my map which is in a array.

But the only public variable from the xMap class i can use is slicedObject which is a linear array holding all the sliced image from a movieclip (this image contain all my object that i want the character to collide with).

So i tryed to do this:

```
package as3
{
public class wl_CollisionDetection
{
    var tChar;
    var tMap;
    public var _CheckCollision:Boolean;
    public function wl_CollisionDetection(xChar:wl_Character,xMap:wl_MapBuilder)
    {
        tChar = xChar;
        tMap = xMap;
    }
    public function CheckCollision()
    {
        _CheckCollision = false;
        if (tChar.character.hitTestObject(tMap.sliceObject[70]))
        {
            _CheckCollision = true;
            trace("Collision detected!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _CheckCollision = false;
            trace("No collision");
            return;
        }
        _CheckCollision = false;
    }
}
}
```

All i get is the no collision trace.

```
if (tChar.character.hitTestObject(tMap.sliceObject[70]))
```

What i’m doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem comes from the fact that you're testing collision with only one object from the map.

Try using a loop:

```
package as3
{
public class wl_CollisionDetection
{
    private var tChar:wl_Character;
    private var tMap:wl_MapBuilder;

    public function wl_CollisionDetection(xChar:wl_Character,xMap:wl_MapBuilder)
    {
        tChar = xChar;
        tMap = xMap;
    }

    public function checkCollision():Boolean
    {
        var numObject:int = tMap.sliceObject.length;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numObject; i++)
        {
            if (tChar.character.hitTestObject(tMap.sliceObject[i]))
            {
                trace("Collision detected!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        trace("No collision");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe if i explain the process a lil more...

I have a main class which load map class and character class. The character class add the character with a addChild(movieclip);. The map class load the image of the map which are stored in a array from a sliced movieclip. It then add them on the stage with addchild(cell0) for ground and addchild(cell1) for object on map. So what i want to do is check if character hit an object on the map. The only way i can see to get this to work is do a hittest with the character and the array containing the movieclip since i dont have access to the cell directly

Comment: What are `cell0` and `cell1` instances of? Are all your movieclips added directly to the stage? You can not  perform a call to `hitTestObject()` by passing it an array for argument as it takes a `DisplayObject`, thus my proposition to use a loop. Is my solution not working at all? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: well nothing is working, i think its my manner to call  the function thats not working:

   if (xCollision.checkCollision() == true)
   {
    trace("Collided");
    return;
   }
   else (xCollision.checkCollision() == false)
   {
    trace("Test");
   }

Comment: im not even on a object and all i see is collided ... if i say if (xCollision.checkCollision == true) then it never goes into the function... i dont know whats wrong really

Comment: cell0 and cell1 are added to stage directly but that kind of movie clip is stored in my array, im using array of movieclip to add them to the stage using cell0 and cell1 (they are a temporary clip of the array)

Comment: sorry im french if i repeat its cause i try to explain it the best i can lol

Comment: i dont use stage.addChild tough... i use addChild(cell0);

Comment: hmm i got it to work... i publically declared my cell1 in my mapbuilding class and im detecting directly on that... it work :\ i was trying to detect on his child i guess.. oh well! still using ur function it work well didnt know how to use function as a boolean so :P thanks!

Comment: Cool! if you use `addChild()` directly from a component, it will be added as a child of this component rather than a direct child of the stage. If you use `stage.addChild()` you can ensure all your movieclips have the same parent. And I'm french as well if it makes things easier to explain next time ;)